# Can an integrator be used as a two way directional valve?

Tags: matlab, controls, real-time, simulink

I am new to designing real time plant models in simulink, and i have to include a 2 way directional valve in my model, i could take the orifice model and make the pressure differentials zero when direction is from B->A. Can i use an integrator to do the same? or is there a more appropriate block that is less complicated?I am using MATLAB 2012b

Thank you!